# Symfony & Doctrine: Undefined index when trying to access one-to-many

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

Im having a bit of problems.
I have 2 classes:
Carorder:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use AppBundle\Entity\Orderdetail;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="carorder")
 */
class Carorder
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orderdetail", mappedBy="Carorder", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     **/
    protected $orderdetails;

    //Then all the auto genereted setters and getters beneath here
```

Orderdetail:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

/** @ORM\Entity 
 *  @ORM\Table(name="orderdetail")
 */
class Orderdetail
{
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Carorder", inversedBy="orderdetails")
     **/
    protected $carorder;
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    protected $amount;

    //Then all the auto generated setters and getters beneath here
```

I can't access the orderdetail through the Carorder. For example this example, just thorws the

```
   Undefined index: Carorder
```

Example:

```
    $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Carorder');
    $orders = $repository->findAll();
    $orderdetail = $orders[0]->getOrderdetails()->first();
```

I have no idea what is causing this, so i hoped you guys could help me out.

Comment: The error pinpoints to the first line in the example you provided?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You mapped the property `Carorder` but your property name is `carorder`, it's case sensitive.

A correct mapping could be:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Orderdetail", mappedBy="carorder", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 **/
protected $orderdetails;
```

Comment: I've spent literally 2 weeks wondering about this. I've looked the OneToMany mapping through 100 times... I was 100% sure that the mapping was correct. Thank you very much